# setBackgroundStyle on NSTextField with an Attributed String Value not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion

OS X 10.7:

Whenever I try to `setBackgroundStyle:` on an `NSTextField`'s cell that has an Attributed String value, the background style is unmodified. If the `NSTextField` has just a String value, the background style setter works.

`[myTextField cell]` returns an object of type `NSTextFieldCell` in both cases, which inherits `setBackgroundStyle:` from `NSCell`.

Anyone have a suggestion on how I can get around this limitation? I know I could try to recreate it with attributes, but I may never be able to get it just right.

P.S. - `NSBackgroundStyleLowered` appears to override your cell's text color (makes mine white), whereas `NSBackgroundStyleRaised` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IME, the NSAttributedString overrides the settings for the NSTextField.